# Is there any way to join two Java LinkedLists in O(1)?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am mostly looking for someone to confirm the following is correct.

1. *It is trivially obvious that joining two linked lists (singly or doubly) into one linked list "tail to head" can be done in O(1) time.*

If we do not have a reference to the tail of the first list, then it is O(n) time where n is the length of the first list, but the important part is that the step where we add the two linked lists together consists of 1 step (linking the tail of the first list to the head of the second)

2. The java utility class LinkedList is an implementation of a the List interface, which internally uses a doubly linked list.

However, because the public interface is that of a List, specific operations that manipulate the nodes and connections are not possible.

*It is not quite correct to say that LinkedList is the same as the doubly linked list ADT*

As such, if our "linked list" is an instance of java.util.LinkedList it *is not* possible to join lists in O(1).

Work I have done so far:
a. I have written my own singly linked list class and used this to demonstrate the O(1) linking behaviour. The behaviour for a doubly linked list is almost identical.
I can post this if requested.

b. I have read the oracle documentation for the LinkedList:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

c. I have looked through the source code of how LinkedLists is actually working:

https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java

As far as I can see, there is nothing here that checks if the two things being combined are both LinkedLists and implements the O(1) adding that I have described above.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to join two Java LinkedLists in O(1)?

No.

You also want to confirm this statement:

> It is trivially obvious that joining two linked lists (singly or doubly) into one linked list "tail to head" can be done in O(1) time.

This is not true, in general.  It is true is some cases, not in others.

It is not true *in general* for list data structures that are encapsulated within an API, such as `LinkedList`.  For encapsulated lists, the API will determine whether this is possible.  For `LinkedList` it is not possible.  The APIs do not allow it ...

However, you *could* design an ADT in which `O(1)` list splicing was possible.  The "catch" is that when you splice the second list to the end of the first, it is no longer a "first class" list.  The semantics are harder to reason about; e.g. the 2nd list can change as a result of operations on the 1st one.  Not all operations will change it.  (This kind of thing is why the standard Java `List` implementations don't support splicing.)

It is also not true *in general* for non-encapsulated lists.  For example, if you (just) have the heads of two singly linked lists, you need to traverse to the tail of the first list before you can splice the second one to the end of it.  The splice is `O(1)` but getting the tail of the first list is `O(N)`.

However, if you implement your linked list in a way that the list object has a link to the head node and the tail node, you don't need the `O(N)` step.

Comment: C++ std::list::splice moves nodes within or between lists. If one or more nodes are moved from a second list to a first list,  no operations on the first list will affect the remaining nodes on the second list.

Comment: OK ... so it depends exactly on the API design and the semantics of splicing.  But the flipside is that that form of split is not `O(1)`.

Comment: For C++ [std::list::splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice), it's O(1) if moving all nodes or one node from one list to another, or if moving a range of nodes within a list. It's O(n) only when moving a range of nodes from one list to another.

Comment: Thank you.

My initial question was a bit unclear. When I said joining "linked list" in O(1) I meant a singly (or doubly, or circularly) linked list and not the java LinkedList

Comment: @SusanSanderson - The title of your question (still) uses the exact words that I quoted.  *"Is there any way to **join two Java LinkedLists** in O(1)?"* That is not in the slightest bit unclear.  And the answer is equally clear. No.  But I also answered your other questions about linked lists in general.

Comment: Please do not change the title of your question to change its meaning.  Let it stand.  People answer the question that you ask.  Even if that answer is not what you want (e.g. because you asked the wrong question) it is still relevant to other people.  If you radically modify the question ... you are invalidating the work that people have spent on answering your original question.

Comment: @StephenC 

Sorry the question was poorly written. It is essentially two questions, one about the Java LinkedList structure, and one about the abstract data structures known as linked lists.

I have since learnt. Yes, you can join two linked lists (the abstract data structures) in O(1) assuming you have a pointer to the tail of the first list. 

And no, this cannot be done with Java LinkedList. This is because Java LinkedList uses the List interface.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to join two Java LinkedLists in O(1)?

No. Unlike C++ std::list::splice(), Java's native linked list does not have the ability to move nodes within a list or between two lists. With C++, std::list::splice() can move all nodes from a second list to a first list, in O(1) time, using begin() or end() or user iterator to specify where to insert or append the second list's nodes to within the first list.

Another is is Java's implementation of iterators. Unlike C++, they can't be shallow copied. If you assign an iterator to a second iterator, both will reference the same iterator object. If you insert or delete any nodes in a Java linked list, it will invalidate all iterators (except for an iterator used as a parameter to insert or delete).

I only know some of the history, that early some in the Java community wanted C++ compatibility, and there were some versions made, but that was abandoned, and ended up with what Java is now.

Answer (score 0):

YES, "there is a way to join two Java `LinkedList`s in O(1)"!

Using reflection and changing (or destroying) the original lists. This solution is very dependent of the Java version and may fail for other versions or implementations - tested with OpenJDK 8. It will eventually also fail if run using a `SecurityManager` and/or missing the corresponding rights.

This code joins the 2nd list into the first and returns the first list:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LLMerge {

    private final Field size;
    private final Field first;
    private final Field last;
    private final Field next;
    private final Field prev;
    
    LLMerge() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        size = LinkedList.class.getDeclaredField("size");
        size.setAccessible(true);
        first = LinkedList.class.getDeclaredField("first");
        first.setAccessible(true);
        last = LinkedList.class.getDeclaredField("last");
        last.setAccessible(true);
        next = first.getType().getDeclaredField("next");
        next.setAccessible(true);
        prev = first.getType().getDeclaredField("prev");
        prev.setAccessible(true);
    }
    
    public <E> LinkedList<E> merge(LinkedList<E> l1, LinkedList<E> l2) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        int size1 = size.getInt(l1);
        Object first1 = first.get(l1);
        Object last1 = last.get(l1);

        int size2 = size.getInt(l2);
        Object first2 = first.get(l2);
        Object last2 = last.get(l2);

        next.set(last1, first2);
        prev.set(first2, last1);
        last.set(l1, last2);
        size.setInt(l1, size1+size2);

        return l1;
    }
}
```

This code is just a prototype, so please note:

1. The second list should not be used after being merged, or risk unexpected behavior since the same `Node`s will be shared between both lists. If that is a problem, code must be added to reset the fields of the second list, basically clearing it.
2. This code also does not handle empty lists correctly - missing `null` checks (`first` and `last` nodes)